# Where should I put `requirements` folder for django login template?

Tags: django, django-login

According to [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required):

> It’s your responsibility to provide the html for the login template ,
>   called **registration/login.html** by default.

Where should I put `registration` folder?

I tried putting it in top folder (same place as `manage.py`). When that didn't work, I added `registration` to the `INSTALLED_APPS` list in `settings.py`. That didn't help either.

I tried putting `registration` in the project folder (next to `settings.py`), and that didn't work either.

My project's `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('myapp', include('myapp.urls')),
    path('login', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='my_login'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: It should go into the `templates` folder of your main app.

Comment: in `myapp/templates`?

Comment: If `myapp` is your main app, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the `registration` folder in the same folder as you defined in the `TEMPLATE` setting in `settings.py`.
So if your app declares `app/template` as a template directory, you need to place the html files in `app/template/registration/`.

```
# settings.py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    ...
    }
]
```